# pre notifcation of an inserted usb device, before enumeration starts in linux?

Tags: linux, usb, enumeration

Please help me, How can i get the pre notifcation of an inserted usb device, before enumeration starts in linux ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libudev](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/libudev/) to get notifications of added/removed devices.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/) for libudev. You can also use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979123/how-to-get-notifications-for-sd-card-events) to get started.

There's also [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) available for usb events/manipulation.

Comment: I am new to Linux, I have a basic question about the above answer, does this libudev usage to detect USB events happens before enumeration? When exactly the enumeration happens ?

If I use the udev rules, will that be before enumeration? But if I use udev i cannot print any message on the console, how can i inform the user about usb detection?

Comment: Test it for yourself, I don't know if `libudev` or `libusb` is enough, or you have to go down another level. Run the sample code and see what happens.